# Arm frequency capped vs currently throttled

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

According to [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md) `vcgencmd get_throttled` can inform about 4 states:

- under-voltage
- arm frequency capped
- throttled
- soft temperature limit active (from my understanding of [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md): non-existent in RPi 4B)

and their past presence. I decided to test thermals in my Raspberry Pi 4B (4GB). Before tests I do `sudo reboot`. While running `stress-ng --cpu 0 --cpu-method fft` (as [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/thermal-testing-raspberry-pi-4/)) I also run my bash script:

```
while :
do
  sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
  vcgencmd measure_temp
  vcgencmd get_throttled
  sleep 1
  echo ''
done
```

Before test I get sth like:

```
600000
temp=56.0'C
throttled=0x0
```

Than while I run test I have:

```
1500000
temp=71.0'C
throttled=0x0
[...]
1500000
temp=82.0'C
throttled=0x20000 [Arm frequency capping has occurred]
[...]
1500000
temp=83.0'C
throttled=0x20002 [Arm frequency capping has occurred, Arm frequency capped]
[...]
1500000
temp=84.0'C
throttled=0x20000  [Arm frequency capping has occurred]

1500000
temp=82.0'C
throttled=0x60002 [Arm frequency capping has occurred, Throttling has occurred, Arm frequency capped]
[...]
```

The state `0x60002` almost stays the same for the rest of the test. Once I managed to see:

```
1500000
temp=83.0'C
throttled=0x60006
```

So here are my questions:

1. What does it mean that "Arm frequency capped" even though I have full frequency?
2. What is the difference between throttling and frequency cap? Why the second one appears much earlier?
3. Why my frequency does not drop at any time of the test even though frequency capped and throttling is reported?

Comment: Good question! What was your documentation source on the value in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`?

Comment: @Seamus Ohh right I've just found it somewhere in the internet... While using `vcgencmd measure_clock arm` I now see that it's caped to ~1 Ghz. Ok so then what's the difference between throttling and cap freq state? And what is measured in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`?

Comment: I don't know... I assumed you had found that somewhere in the documentation published by [`The Organization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation).

Comment: for measuring the cpu clock (which will be the same for all cores) instead of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` do either `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` or `vcgencmd measure_clock arm`

Answer (score 3):

`Arm frequency capping has occurred` means that at some point, **since last boot**, capping has occurred, but that doesn't mean the cpu is currently capped

i.e. in the one second between the previous reading and the current reading the frequency WAS capped, but is no longer capped (right now) ...

Also, you want to measure `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` rather than `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`

Measuring `scaling_cur_freq` gives actual cpu clock - not sure about the reason for this `scaling_*_freq` vs `cpuinfo_*_freq` entries

see [this unix.stackexchange.com post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/why-do-cpuinfo-cur-freq-and-proc-cpuinfo-report-different-numbers) for more info on `scaling_*_freq` vs `cpuinfo_*_freq`

a better(? since you don't need sudo) measurement can be made using

```
vcgencmd measure_clock arm
```

so, the monitoring script would look like

```
while :
do
  vcgencmd measure_clock arm
  vcgencmd measure_temp
  vcgencmd get_throttled
  sleep 1
  echo ''
done
```

As for throttling vs capping. I did read that throttling happens for undervoltage condition vs capping is for overheating

My piB 2 has a poor power supply and always gets an undervoltage condition during boot, hence `throttled=0x50000` at boot ... undervoltage + throttled has occurred (since boot)

Comment: thx! "throttling happens for undervoltage condition" - so why then udervoltage is not reported (16. bit is 0)?

Comment: yeah, I know ... perhaps other things also cause throttling